# Why do some questions display the wrong user in the "Unanswered" list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

While browsing the Unanswered Questions I noticed this:

[image]

I clicked through [to the question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/45801/29228) and the user in the picture is nowhere to be found.

I also noticed a similar issue with [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/71192/29228), so it is not specific to one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question list shows you the user who most-recently answered the question or edited a post in the thread.

In both of these cases, however, the users modification (an answer) was subsequently deleted. If you have the reputation to see deleted posts, it would be somewhat more obvious.

It's just a quirk of the software, not (as far as I know) a bug.

Comment: Is there somewhere that explains why this is the design?

Comment: I'm sure there's a post on it on the meta for SO or SE (since that's where I learned about the behavior), but it's a little tricky to search for. I haven't found it yet.